# Data Organization, by Country and Year

Tags: excel, data-cleaning

I currently have a spreadsheet of data that I am cleaning to import into a database for further analysis. Currently the format is this:

```
    Country | Year | GDP
    --------------------
    USA     | 1950 | 5
    USA     | 1951 | 6
    ...
    GBR     | 1950 | 4
    GBR     | 1951 | 5
```

And so on for many countries. What I want to do is transpose this data so that it is a table of Country by Year and each cell is a coordinate GDP(Country, Year). i.e.:

```
Country | 1950 | 1951 | ...
-------------------------
USA     |  5   |  6  ... 
GBR     |  4   |  5
```

Is there an easy way to do such a transposition? I realize it does not work because each country is iterated over 'n' years so a classic transposition is unavailable, but the nice thing is the table is uniform in that each country has rows from 1950-2011. My workflow includes Excel, R and SQLite. Is there a way to structure an sql script to import the rows in this manner? I usually use a csv-to-sql converter tool but I want the db table structured in the manner of the second table.

The underlying reason for this task is that I am gathering health data from WHO (formatted like the second table) and economic indicators from Penn (formatted as in the first table), and going to look at correlations between the two, thus I want all tables to have the same schema, as to ensure the relational aspect of the database is intuitive. I tell you this because I figure someone might have an idea/workaround that might make my original request unnecessary/extraneous.

Comment: These are common data manipulations. You want to search for "long to wide" (or to go back, "wide to long").

Comment: Thank you @gung ! I knew it had to be something simple, I don't suppose you know a simple method of performing this in SQL? I've only figured out how to do it in R so far.

Comment: If you just want `SQL` code to do this, that would be off topic here, but on topic on [SO]. We'll migrate your Q there.